# How do I get field name from unique constraint exception in JPA

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I understand that if I try to insert a record using JPA and if it violates unique constrain, it throws an exception which contains cause MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException.

I want to show user friendly message to the user. So I would like to get the field name for which violation occured. I can get the message using cause which gives message something like Duplicate entry '1' for key 'DOCUMENT_NUMBER'.

But I feel relying on message(e.getCause().getCause().getMessage()) is not a good idea.

The entity may contain several other unique constraints like emailid, vat number etc.

So I would like to get the field name for which constraint violation occured.

Could some one please help how to get the field name?

Thanks in advance,
Kitty

Answer (score 0):

you can try below code

```
try{

     //here your code
     ...
}catch (ConstraintViolationException e) {
        for(ConstraintViolation violation : e.getConstraintViolations()) {
            System.out.println(violation.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Also for detail explanation of `ConstraintViolationException` see [Java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/ConstraintViolationException.html).

Comment: There is no method getConstraintViolations() for ConstriantViolationException.

Comment: what is this then https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/ConstraintViolationException.html#getConstraintViolations()

Comment: it was my bad, I was referring to the Hibernate/Java Persistence type of ConstraintViolationException. (org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException)